# javascript issue in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint

I write this coding in C# in my sharepoint project. It works well.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ale", "window.open('DownloadHandler.ashx?fileName=Error.log');", true);
```

But when I change my coding to this, it no longer works.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ale", string.Format("window.open('DownloadHandler.ashx?fileName={0}')", "Error.log"), true);
```

What's wrong with my coding?

Comment: Define "no longer works", please?

Comment: I don't know, there's a missing `;` at the end of the `window.open()` statement?

Comment: @kevin Missing Semicolon at the end of javascript??

Comment: no longer works mean, it does not download the file at all.

Comment: Ohh Thanks a lot, yes it's the semi colon **;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a missing `;` at the end of the `window.open()` statement:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), 
    "ale", 
    string.Format("window.open('DownloadHandler.ashx?fileName={0}');", "Error.log"),
    true
);
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why this lack of a semicolon would cause it to stop working, since [Javascript has automatic semicolon insertion](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/).

Comment: @PeterOlson - I'm not sure, since I was thinking the same thing (minor error in Javascript). Maybe IE throws an error and stops execution if a statement is not ended? I'm wondering the same thing. It was the only problem I saw with the example code.

Comment: Script registrar may have other scripts after it which are added together, thus rendering the script in error. This script string is processed by .net before it is executed by javascript.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski - That was my second guess, which was something else was happening that threw the actual on-page script off. Always best to inspect what the browser sees vis-a-vis Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

So it's missing a semi colon `;` at the end.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ale", string.Format("window.open('DownloadHandler.ashx?fileName={0}');", "Error.log"), true);
```